# PostMessage Issues Using IFrame in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, postmessage

I have two buttons that work differently. The first one is when you click the reload button, it should reload the page. The second one is when you click it, it will show the alert on the page.
I'm using `postMessage` because its inside the iframe. I'm not sure why the two buttons are not working but I already implemented the `postMessage` and `window.onmessage`

**CODESANDBOX**

1. [PARENT WINDOW](https://codesandbox.io/s/cross-origin-iframe-forked-eq0o2y?file=/index.html)
2. [CHILD PAGE](https://codesandbox.io/s/8beu4h?file=/index.html)

**CODE**

```
function reloadPage() {
  window.parent.postMessage({ reload: true }, 'https://8beu4h.csb.app');
}

function alertPage() {
  window.parent.postMessage({ alert: true }, 'https://8beu4h.csb.app');
}

    window.onmessage = (event) => {
      const { data, origin, source } = event;
      if (source == frameToListen.contentWindow) {
        try {
          if (data.reload) {
            window.location.reload();
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
    };
    window.onmessage = (event) => {
      const { data, origin, source } = event;
      if (source == frameToListen.contentWindow) {
        try {
          if (data.alert) {
            alert("HI");
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Joseph, Kaiido's answer here appears to make sense to me and TBH I don't think I could provide a better/improved answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Parent Window**

```
window.addEventListener(
  "message",
  function (event) {
    const { data, source } = event;
    console.log(source);
    if (source == frameToListen.contentWindow) {
      if (data.reload) window.location.reload();
      if (data.alert) alert("HI");
    }
  },
  false
);
```

**CHILD WINDOW**

```
function reloadPage() {
  window.parent.postMessage({ reload: true }, 'https://eq0o2y.csb.app/');
}

function alertPage() {
  window.parent.postMessage({ alert: true }, 'https://eq0o2y.csb.app/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `Window.postMessage()` is the target origin, not the source one.

Change

```js
postMessage({ reload: true }, 'https://8beu4h.csb.app');
```

to

```js
postMessage({ reload: true }, 'https://eq0o2y.csb.app');
```

Also, `onmessage` can only set one handler at a time. Your second one will remove the previous one. Either you merge both handlers in a single function, either you use `addEventListener()`

Comment: Can you fork my codesandbox? Thank you

Comment: Would that really help you? I don't have nor want to create an account.

Comment: Yes it would. You don't have to create an account. you can fork it without needing an account

Comment: should I change both `postMessage` link to 'https://eq0o2y.csb.app'? We'll I wanted to click the button from this page `https://eq0o2y.csb.app/`

Comment: and I'm not sure how to do this? `Either you merge both handlers in a single function, either you use addEventListener()`. Can you write the code down?

Comment: Yes you change both, the second argument is the target url, if you want to talk to eq0o2y, you put that. As for addEventListener you really never saw that before? Surprising you're already messing with postMessage without ever seeing how to add event listeners. Anyway, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener